# Why is Ubuntu menu display corrupted on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

After upgrading VirtualBox my Ubuntu VM is having problems displaying the menu and window management controls (maximize/close).

Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot of corrupt menu display]

VirtualBox Version 5.1.30 r118389 (Qt5.6.2)
Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: May be an issue with host GPU integration into Guest Additions. Try with updating VirtualBox (at present 5.2.2.)

Comment: @Takkat Thanks for the suggestion. I upgraded to 5.2.2 and also updated the Guest Additions. Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: This question doesn't look like a bug question to me. This looks like an ordinary software solution question.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling "3D Acceleration" prevents  the screen corruption from occurring.